# How do I view the JSON behind a Google Slide?

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

I want to know what elements of a slide can be changed programmatically; one way to understand what's going on would be to look at the JSON behind slides.  I have the slides ID but haven't figured out how to look at it in any way except the standard wysiwyg editor.

Answer (score 0):

For the whole presentation, you can check [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations).

JSON representation

```
{
  "presentationId": string,
  "pageSize": {
    object(Size)
  },
  "slides": [
    {
      object(Page)
    }
  ],
  "title": string,
  "masters": [
    {
      object(Page)
    }
  ],
  "layouts": [
    {
      object(Page)
    }
  ],
  "locale": string,
  "revisionId": string,
  "notesMaster": {
    object(Page)
  },
}
```

And for each page, you can refer to [REST Resource: presentations.pages](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages).

JSON representation

```
{
  "objectId": string,
  "pageType": enum(PageType),
  "pageElements": [
    {
      object(PageElement)
    }
  ],
  "revisionId": string,
  "pageProperties": {
    object(PageProperties)
  },

  // Union field properties can be only one of the following:
  "slideProperties": {
    object(SlideProperties)
  },
  "layoutProperties": {
    object(LayoutProperties)
  },
  "notesProperties": {
    object(NotesProperties)
  },
  "masterProperties": {
    object(MasterProperties)
  },
  // End of list of possible types for union field properties.
}
```

Comment: Can I present slide using this JSON response in Android ?

@MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0